# adding another item object in existing list after every 3 items

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I just simply want to add item after every 3 item  so basically i want to add `adsItemObject` to a Existing List after every 3 items Existing List.

For Example `1.DataList 2. AdsList`
Now, I want to add item of `AdsList` to `DataList` after every 3 Items of `DataList` like u can say .

```
  List<Ads> AdsList = new ArrayList<>();
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads1"));
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads2"));
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads3"));



                List<Jobs> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs1"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs2"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs3"));
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads1"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs4"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs5"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs6"));
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads2"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs7"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs8"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs9"));
                AdsList.add(new Ads("Ads3"));
                DataList.add(new Jobs("Jobs10"));
```

Above Example is Manually i want to to be dynamically

Comment: Your question needs revising, please consider adding more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Try like this to add items in existing list after every 3 items:**

```
List<String> AdsList = new ArrayList();
        AdsList.add("Ads1");
        AdsList.add("Ads2");
        AdsList.add("Ads3");

        List<String> DataList = new ArrayList<>();
        DataList.add("Jobs1");
        DataList.add("Jobs2");
        DataList.add("Jobs3");
        DataList.add("Jobs4");//
        DataList.add("Jobs5");
        DataList.add("Jobs6");
        DataList.add("Jobs7");//
        DataList.add("Jobs8");
        DataList.add("Jobs9");
        DataList.add("Jobs10");//


for(int i = AdsList.size(); i >= 1; i--) {
    if((i*3) < DataList.size() && (i-1) < AdsList.size()) {
       DataList.add(i*3, AdsList.get(i-1));
    } 
}
Log.i(TAG,"DataList "+Arrays.toString(DataList.toArray()));
Output:- DataList [Jobs1, Jobs2, Jobs3, Ads1, Jobs4, Jobs5, Jobs6, Ads2, Jobs7, Jobs8, Jobs9, Ads3, Jobs10]
```

**Note:-** If your lists are not fixed size, don't forgot to make check conditions for length, otherwise you can get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: can u implement notes in example?